# Herencia múltiple en PHP – Alternativa(s)

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una **Application Programming Interface**, y necesito una característica o método para soportar la **herencia múltiple** en PHP.

Código:

```
<?php

class CreateUrl extends Endpoint, Authenticable, RateLimited, Url{
 /* Cuerpo de la clase
  */
}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Es una lastima el tiempo que he perdido hoy, mi unico dia de la semana. De todas maneras, alguna alternativa? Alguien?

Comment: Lo que yo haria es una Funcion multiple pero Tu quieres una class yo hace tiempo mire este video espero te ayude :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7oDUnQmHTI

Comment: Hola @FabricioDíaz Si deseas que tu respuesta sea bien recibida revisa [ask], veo que no has realizado el [tour] para saber como funcionamos.

Answer (score 7):

La herencia múltiple acarrea el [problema del diamante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante). Cuando una clase requiere heredar mas de una clase, es signo de que algo anda mal en el diseño y se estaria violando el [principio de responsabilidad unica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica).

Puedo ver 2 soluciones a tu situacion: [Composicion sobre herencia](https://devexperto.com/herencia-vs-composicion/) o utilizar [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

**Intefaces:**

[java](/questions/tagged/java) esta basado en interfaces y se les puede sacar partido en php también. Las interfaces es una herramienta que termine **emular** herencia múltiple creando un contrato con la clase cliente pero sin especificar una implementación definida:

```
public interface IAuthenticableService 
{
  public function getAuth();
}
public interface IEndpointService
{
  public function getEndPoint();
}

public class CreateUrl implements IEndpointService, IAuthenticableService 
{


   function getEndPoint()  
   { 
     return new EndPoint(); // aqui puedes retornar cualquier EndPoint
   }
   public function getAuth()
   {
       return new Authenticable(); // aqui puedes retornar cualquier Authenticable 
   }
}

public function validarEndPoint(IEndPointService service)
{
   $endPoint = service->getEndPoint(); // obtenemos el servicio EndPoint
   // verificacion de endpoint
   //..
}
public function authenticate(IAuthenticableService $auth)
{
   $success = $auth->authenticate("sa","123");
   return $success;
}



   $urlCreator = new CreateUrl();
    validarEndPoint($urlCreator);
    authenticate($urlCreator);
```

**Composición sobre herencia:**

Esto te permite que tu clase se componga de un o mas objectos. Es como si estuviésemos delegando una funcionalidad a un objeto que si sabe como hacerla.

```
public class Carro
{

    $motor;
    $ruedas;
    $pintura;
    public __construct(Motor $motor, Ruedas $ruedas, Pintura $pintura)
    {
        $this->$motor = $motor;
        $this->ruedas = $ruedas;
        $this->pintura = $pintura;

        $this->ruedas->aplicar($this);
        $this->pintura->pintar($this);
    }

    public function correr()
    {
        $this->motor->iniciar($this);   
    }

    public function parar()
    {
        $this->motor->detener();
    }

    public function reparar()
    {
        $this->motor->aplicarAceite();
        $this->pintura->pintar($this);
        $this->ruedas->cambiar();
    }
}

$carroPolicia = new Carro(new Motor(2.4, "gasolina", "injección de nitrógeno"), new Ruedas(4), new PinturaAzul());

$carroPolica->correr();
```

En el ejemplo de arriba, si el carro heredara de motor, entonces estaríamos diciendo que el carro es un motor y por lo tanto sabe como funciona el motor a detalle, al igual tendría que saber el funcionamiento de como se aplica la pintura y ruedan las ruedas. Es un objeto muy complejo. Así que mejor le delegamos esa tarea a objetos que si saben hacerlo, como por ejemplo la clase Motor, y así nos quitamos la responsabilidad de tener que verificar necesita aceite, sino que lo hace la propia clase Motor.

Comment: Buenísima respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Se puede lograr utilizando trait, el siguiente ejemplo muestra el detalle

```
<?php
trait message1 {
  public function msg1() {
    echo "OOP is fun! ";
  }
}

trait message2 {
  public function msg2() {
    echo "OOP reduces code duplication!";
  }
}

class Welcome {
  use message1;
}

class Welcome2 {
  use message1, message2;
}

$obj = new Welcome();
$obj->msg1();
echo "<br>";

$obj2 = new Welcome2();
$obj2->msg1();
$obj2->msg2();
?>
```

Comment: Considera explicar cómo esto soluciona el problema