# ¿Cómo realizar herencia múltiple en PHP?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes,

Estoy trabajando en una API utilizando PHP como lenguaje de programación principal integrado en los distintos **endpoints**.

Todo bien, hasta cuando es hora de mover los archivos de mi **IDE** a el servidor web, y resulta en diversos errores de `unexpected ','`, en la línea en donde se empiezan todas las clases.

### ¿Cuál es el problema?

Mi aplicación necesita heredar de más de una clase, nótese el problema en `extends`:

```
<?php

class Endpoint1 extends service, Short{
 // Métodos y propiedades
}
```

### ¿Qué he intentado?

He intentado utilizar los conocidos **traits**, pero eso **arruinaría la infraestructura de mi API**, en el sentido de que, las propiedades no se heredan y, algunas clases que heredo en, por ejemplo la clase `Endpoint1` heredan de otras clases también y a veces implementan interfaces.

### ¿Qué necesito?

Alguna alternativa a los **traits**, incluso algún *add-on* para PHP que me permitiese concretar lo que necesito: **herencia múltiple**, o, en caso contrario, alguna alternativa.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94658/herencia-m%C3%BAltiple-en-php-alternativas) el codigo sugiere una similitud

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo @IvanBotero, es otro usuario, y para colmo la otra tampoco tiene respuesta. desgraciadamente, tenemos que tener fe que es otro OP buscando una repuesta similar.

Comment: @gbianchi Si, es otro usuario, solo hacia la observacion ya que curiosamente el codigo extendia las mismas clases en el mismo orden, pero igual no tiene respuesta, asi que no es un duplicado aun

Comment: @Andres Valle No hay forma, la solución es usar traits si es lo que buscas es heredar múltiples clases, la misma documentación de php explica porqué...

Comment: @nikomaster Hice lo que me dijiste, estoy utilizando **traits**, diciéndole adiós a mi implementación al mismo tiempo, pero, consigo errores `Triat Triat1 not found`.. me dí cuenta que al incluir la clases inmediatamente requiere de los traits, pero la foreach() loop debe terminar para que se cargen los traits. Como soluciono esto? Ni si quiera instancie las clases y ya,me pide los traits.

Comment: @AndresValle No entiendo a lo que te refieres, muéstrame un pastebin como ejemplo...