# Diferenciación de clases y constructores en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con objetos y me surge una duda en cuanto a la división de clases y constructores de las mismas cuando tengo herencia.

Si tengo una clase padre que contiene las propiedades generales de un objeto y una clase hijo que contiene las propiedades específicas de éste (supongamos que tengo una clase padre "artículo" y el hijo es "camiseta" y "bolsa", en camiseta tendré la propiedad "manga", puesto que es una característica que bolsa no tiene y a la inversa si tuviera "asas".)

¿El constructor estaría correctamente declarado de esta forma?

```
class Articulo{

    protected $talla;
    protected $color;
    protected $composicion;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
        $this->talla=$talla;
        $this->color=$color;
        $this->composicion=$composicion;
    }
}

class Camiseta extends Articulo{

    protected $mangas=2;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
        parent::__construct($talla, $color, $composicion);
    }
}

class Bolsa extends Articulo{

    protected $asas=2;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
        parent::__construct($talla, $color, $composicion);
    }
}

$camiseta= new Camiseta('S', 'Rojo', 'Algodón');
$bolsa= new Bolsa('U', 'Azul', 'Poliester');
```

o tendria por el contrario que hacer lo siguiente en el constructor de bolsas y camisetas:

```
public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
    $this->talla=$talla;
    $this->color=$color;
    $this->composicion=$composicion;
    $this->asas=$asas;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si sigues los fundamentos de la POO, lo mejor es agregar al constructor de la clase hija los atributos propios de ella:

- El constructor de `Camiseta` recibirá adicionalmente el atributo `$mangas`. Aquí se da un caso interesante: si una camiseta tendrá siempre dos mangas, tendrías que invalidar el `setter` respectivo a mangas, de lo contrario la clase tendrá fallos de concepción.
- El constructor de `Bolso` recibirá adicionalmente el atributo `$asas`.

Luego, al crear el objeto, según del tipo que sea, le pasas el parámetro suplementario al constructor, ejemplo:

```
$bolsa= new Bolsa('U', 'Azul', 'Poliester',2);
```

#### `Código:` <kbd>[Demo en Rextester](http://rextester.com/KEUMRN69797)</kbd>

```
<?php 


class Articulo{

    protected $talla;
    protected $color;
    protected $composicion;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
        $this->talla=$talla;
        $this->color=$color;
        $this->composicion=$composicion;
    }

 public function getTalla() {
      return $this->talla;
  }

  public function setTalla($talla) {
        $this->talla=$talla;

  }

}

class Camiseta extends Articulo{

    protected $mangas=2;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion,$mangas){
        parent::__construct($talla, $color, $composicion);
    }

    public function getMangas() {
          return $this->mangas;
    }

    public function setMangas($mangas) {
            $this->mangas=$mangas;

    }


}

class Bolsa extends Articulo{

    protected $asas=2;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion,$asas){
        parent::__construct($talla, $color, $composicion);
    }

    public function getAsas() {
          return $this->asas;
    }

    public function setAsas($asas) {
            $this->asas=$asas;

    }


}

$camiseta= new Camiseta('S', 'Rojo', 'Algodón','M');
echo "CAMISETA:".PHP_EOL;
echo "Talla:" .$camiseta->getTalla().PHP_EOL; 
$camiseta->setTalla('XL'); 
echo "Talla nueva:" . $camiseta->getTalla().PHP_EOL; 

echo "***".PHP_EOL;

echo "Mangas: ".$camiseta->getMangas().PHP_EOL; 
$camiseta->setMangas(1); //Nueva moda :) 
echo "Mangas nueva: ".$camiseta->getMangas().PHP_EOL; 

echo PHP_EOL."BOLSA:".PHP_EOL;


$bolsa= new Bolsa('U', 'Azul', 'Poliester',2);

echo "Asas: ".$bolsa->getAsas().PHP_EOL; 
$bolsa->setAsas(4); //Nueva moda :) 
echo "Asas nueva: ".$bolsa->getAsas().PHP_EOL; 

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
CAMISETA:
Talla:S
Talla nueva:XL
***
Mangas: 2
Mangas nueva: 1

BOLSA:
Asas: 2
Asas nueva: 4
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración! Me sirvió de mucho tu código ;-)

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal que veo con tu diseño es que interpretas que todos los archivos definen una talla cuando no es cierto. Una hamburguesa es un articulo pero no se le mide por talla por lo que ya tendras un problema a larga escala.

Intenta definir las propiedades basicas de un articulo:

```
class Articulo{


    protected $color;
    protected $composicion;

    public function __construct( $color, $composicion){
        $this->color=$color;
        $this->composicion=$composicion;
    }
}
```

Entonces crea una entidad base que servira para todos los articulos que requieran talla:

```
public class ArticuloConMedidaBase extends Articulo
{
    protected $mangas=2;
    protected $talla;
    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){

        parent::__construct($color, $composicion);
        $this->$talla = $talla;
    }
}
```

Asi todos los articulos que requieran de una talla solo deben de heredar de la clase `ArticuloConMedidaBase`:

```
class Bolsa extends ArticuloConMedidaBase{
 protected $asas=2;

    public function __construct($talla, $color, $composicion){
        parent::__construct($talla, $color, $composicion);
    }
}
```

Asi entonces vas creando clases bases de cada grupo de articulo con sus propiedades especificas a su grupo. Esto hace que el codigo sea mas facil de mantener y modificar. Otra venta de esto es que si siempre heredas de Articulo y por cambios de requirimientos tienes que agregarle otro parametro al constructor, todas las clases que heredan de Articulos se veran afectadas pero en este caso solo las clases bases de cada grupo de articulos.

Nota personal: La herencia se convierte *facilmente* en un dolor de cabeza si no se sabe utilizar. [Respondi hace un tiempo una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94658/herencia-m%C3%BAltiple-en-php-alternativas/94777#94777) que trataba algo similiar por si quieres darle una miradita.

Answer (score 0):

Si estaria bien declarado

Puedes probarlo agregando

```
public function getCamiseta(){
    return $this->mangas;
}
```

y al final en la prueba

```
echo $camiseta->getCamiseta();
```

Ya la logica de la clase es descuerdo a tus necesidades o del negocio.

Un ejemplo muy parecido esta en el [manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php)